# Catch hold of or get hold of

Tags: usage

What is the error in the following sentence

> We swam up to the drowning man, caught hold of his clothes           before he could go down again and pulled him out, safe to the shore.

On googling I found that **catch hold of** is wrongly used here, instead **get hold of** should be used

But according to < a href= "https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/to-catch-hold-of-something"> collins dictionary  they both mean the same.

Answer (score 1):

"On googling" here may have given you some wrong advice.

My belief is that "caught" would be better than "got" in this context, as it bears the connotation of reaching out deliberately to take hold of something.

"Get" has none of these nuances, and merely implies that a hold on the clothing came into the hand of the subject, without any extra information as to how it happened.

Basically, "get" is weaker and less effective.

Where did you find that bad advice?